On the definition of parameter dependent integral function
I have the following theorem about parameter dependent integral function.
Thm. Let $(X,\mathcal{M})$ a measurable space, $\mu:\mathcal{M} \to [0,+\infty]$ a positive measure,  $(Y,\tau)$ a first countable topological space, $f:X\times Y \to [-\infty,+\infty]$ such that $f(\bullet, y)\in \mathcal{L}^1(\mu), \hspace{4pt} \forall y\in Y$.
Define $$\varphi:Y\to [-\infty, +\infty], \quad \varphi(y)=\int_X f(\bullet, y)\ d\mu$$
If $y_0\in Y$, if $f(x,\bullet)$ is continuous in $y_0$ for a.e. $x\in X$, if $\exists U$ a neighborhood of $y_0$ and $\exists g\in \mathcal{L}^1(\mu)$ such that $\forall y\in U, \hspace{4pt} |f(x,y)|\leq g(x), \hspace{4pt}$ for a.e. $x\in X$, then $\varphi$ is continuous at $y_0$.
I don't understand the notation $$\int_X f(\bullet, y)\ d\mu$$
What are the variables and what are the parameters? Does the bullet mean that the component of $f$ is fixed? Please I need to clarify this thing to understand the statement of the theorem.
A practical example might be useful.
Furthermore, I was wondering why the hypothesis that $Y$ is first countable is assumed, I think it is needed to be able to use continuity for sequences in the proof but I'm not sure, suggestions?

The notation means $\int_X f(\cdot, y) d\mu = \int_X f(x,y) d\mu(x)$, so $y$ is a parameter and you integrate with respect to the variable $x$ and the measure $\mu$.

Thank you! And what about the other thing? If the theorem statement looks correct for you?
